# typeerror: not enough arguments for format string PYTHON

Tags: python, string

I'm learning python 2.7.8.I don't know whats wrong,I've tried all the answers posted. Here's the code:

```
formatterb = "%r %r %r %r"
print formatterb % (
    "I am tired", 
    "Not so tired tho"
    "this had better work.", 
    "been at this for a while")
```

And here' the error message I get:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format strings.
```

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a comma between `"Not so tired tho" "this had better work."`, so there are therefore not enough arguments.

It should be:

```
formatterb = "%r %r %r %r"
print formatterb % (
    "I am tired", 
    "Not so tired tho",
    "this had better work.", 
    "been at this for a while")
```

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

You can't have 4 format specifiers in the string but only 3 elements in the accompanying tuple. If you want the 2nd and 3rd arguments to be on the same line, they should be the same argument, i.e. `"Not so tired tho this had better work"`.

If you want items on separate lines, in general you can add a newline, e.g.:

```
formatterb = "%r %r %r"
print formatterb % (
    "I am tired", 
    "Not so tired tho\nthis had better work.", 
    "been at this for a while")
```

The `\n` will add a newline in between the two substrings. In either case you would want to remove one of the format specifiers.

However, also note that `%r` is equivalent to `repr`, so you'll see the actual string contents, not as it would be printed. e.g. even with the newline, you will see `\n` and not an actual newline.

If you replace `%r` with `%s`, it will show how it would be printed, and you would see it output like this:

```
I am tired Not so tired tho
this had better work. been at this for a while
```

Comment: What is the name of modulo when used like this?

Comment: Yeah,that's because I want them on separate lines not on 1 line @khampson

Comment: @kpie - not sure what you're asking. Are you referring to the `%r`?

Comment: Sure, no problem. Please accept the answer since it appears it has answered your question.